# WCF - Remote server returned an error: 404

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am new to WCF and i am trying to host my first WCF application in a different machine. It works in my local machine from IIS. I hosted in the remote machine and i am able to view the WSDL. I have enabled anonymous authentication as well.

Problem is when i try to test my .svc with SOAP UI, it errors out saying

Error loading [http://domain.com/folder/wcfservice.svc?xsd=xsd0]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream

So, i tried using svcutil command and it errors out with

> > Attempting to download metadata from 'http: //domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or
> >     DISCO. Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http:
> >     //domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl WS-Metadata Exchange Error
> >     URI: http: //domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl Metadata contains a
> >     reference that cannot be resolved: 'http:
> >     //domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl'.
>
> There was no endpoint listening at http: //domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.HTTP GET Error
>       URI: http ://domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?wsdl     The document was understood, but it could not be processed.    The WSDL document
>   contains links that could not be resolved.    There was an error
>   downloading 'http ://domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.    The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive.    Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Here is my webconfig for your reference.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="defaultBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="10.00:00:00"/>
        </behavior>

      <behavior name="metadataSupport">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        <!--Enable WSDL Data Binding-->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />    
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wcfservice.SSO"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="wcfservice.wcfservice_Service" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>   
            <add baseAddress="http://domain.com/folder/wcfService.svc" />   
          </baseAddresses>  
        </host>
        <endpoint address="xml"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wcfservice.SSO"
                  contract="wcfservice.Iwcfservice" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I think its worthwhile to mention that this WCF application was created in VS2012 and i just changed the targetframework to 4.0 in web.config after deployment.

Can somebody please help what is causing the error? Am i missing something in web.config?

Comment: is this a java application trying to use the service, just curious as i see you posted a java.io error.  try using the WCFTestClient to see if that can connect.  It comes with Visual Studio, if you need help using it try this site: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/wcf-test-client/

Comment: java error is from the soapUI, the utility we use to test webserivces. I will try WCFTestClient. Thanks